# image_append on dynamic number of variables

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a directory of images and I want to combine anywhere from 3-10 of the images dynamically. It will be anywhere from 3-10 images. My thought was to create *n* variables and just pass those *n* variables to `image_append`. Is there a way to pass my list of *image1,image2,image3...* to `image_append`?

```
library(magick)
these=list.files('../Desktop/',pattern = '.tif') ##list of images, could be 3-10
for (h in 1:3){
assign(paste("image", h, sep = ""), image_read(these[h]) %>%
         image_annotate(.,strsplit(these[h],'_')[[1]][4],color = 'white',size=30))
}
image_append(c(image1,image2,image3)) ##Works, but there will be an unknown number of *image* vars created

combine_images = function(...){z=image_append(c(...));return(z)} ##Function that can combine a dynamic number, but passing ls(pattern='image') does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the images in the global environment, store it in a list. That way, instead of looping, you can just `lapply` your calls:

```r
library(magick)

these <- list.files('../Pictures/', pattern = '.tif', full.names = TRUE) 

pictures <- image_append(do.call("c", lapply(these, function(h){
 image_annotate(image_read(h), strsplit(h, '[.]')[[1]][1], color = 'white', size = 30)
 })))
```

So now, in my case, I get the following result:

```
pictures
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm...Thought i tried this, but I was trying something like do.call(image_read,...) instead of the 'c'